# How to get filenames based on if-statement?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am searching for images in a folder containing certain colors. I can plot the images, but I can't figure out how to get a list of the filenames. I suspect there might be a simple solution to my problem, which is: how do I get the filenames from the images that match a certain color?

Here is what I am doing:

````
IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'path'
COLORS = {
    'GREEN': [0, 128, 0],
    'BLUE': [0, 0, 128],
    'YELLOW': [255, 255, 0]
}
images = []

for file in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY):
    if not file.startswith('.'):
        images.append(get_image(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, file)))



def match_image_by_color(image, color, threshold = 60, number_of_colors = 10): 
    
    image_colors = get_colors(image, number_of_colors, False)
    selected_color = rgb2lab(np.uint8(np.asarray([[color]])))

    select_image = False
    for i in range(number_of_colors):
        curr_color = rgb2lab(np.uint8(np.asarray([[image_colors[i]]])))
        diff = deltaE_cie76(selected_color, curr_color)
        if (diff < threshold):
            select_image = True
    
    return select_image



def show_selected_images(images, color, threshold, colors_to_match):
    index = 1
    
    for i in range(len(images)):
        selected = match_image_by_color(images[i],
                                        color,
                                        threshold,
                                        colors_to_match)
        if (selected):
            plt.subplot(1, 5, index)
            plt.imshow(images[i])
            index += 1


#Search for GREEN
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
show_selected_images(images, COLORS['GREEN'], 60, 5) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick and dirty solution, you can store tuples of `(filename, image)` in the list instead of just `image`:

```
for file in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY):
    if not file.startswith('.'):
        images.append((file, get_image(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, file))))
                      ^^^^^^^                                              ^

...

        selected = match_image_by_color(images[i][1],
                                                 ^^^
                                        color,
                                        threshold,
                                        colors_to_match)
        if (selected):
            print(f'Selected image {images[i][0]}')
                                             ^^^
            plt.subplot(1, 5, index)
            plt.imshow(images[i][1])
                                ^^^
            index += 1
```

For a cleaner solution, you could create a wrapper class that contains both the file name and the image. You might find that `match_image_by_color` can then be added as a method onto that class as well.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, your quick and dirty solution did it!